# How do I use 2 WHERE clauses including two tables wherein a column in a Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I try to use different columns within different tables.
Like I want it to run the query If or Where [table.column]

```
users.username = 'ExampleUsername' AND users.cardnumber = ''
```

I don't think I can use NULL instead of '', because its an empty text string?

```
users.cardnumber = NULL
```

Anyways, I couldn't come further as this:

```
INSERT INTO users (cardnumber, hasone)
WHERE users.username = 'ExampleName' AND users.cardnumber = ''
SELECT number, sethasone
FROM cards
WHERE cards.used = '0'
LIMIT 1
```

I'm a bit of new with SQL, but after I got it right I could put the code into my php script.

-
SOLVED!   :

I've used two queries for each column.

```
update users
set hasone=(select sethasone from cards where used='0' LIMIT 1)
where username='TestUser'
```

and

```
update users
set cardnumber=(select number from cards where used='0' LIMIT 1)
where username='TestUser'
```

then I just deleted the row from cards and I was done.

```
delete from cards
where used = '1'
LIMIT 1
```

I gave the user a cardnumber from the table cards and delete that row in cards.

Comment: How do the `cards` table and the `users` table relate to each other?

Comment: Where clause is only applied for existing records not for insert statement may be you need update statement instead of insert

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you show us a sample?

Comment: @GoatCO They are in the same database. The database that i'm using as default.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid So i could use UPDATE?

Comment: @Dexter As your question is unclear,please update your question with the details that you need to insert new rows in users table or you need to update your users table ?

Comment: @Mureinik I try to copy the data from one row in the table 'cards' from the columns number, sethasone [1, 2] to the table 'users' into the columns cardnumber, hasone [1, 2]. But only where the value of the column 'username' in table 'users' = 'ExampleName' AND column 'cardnumber' in table 'users' = '' and only copy the data from the table 'cards' column 'number' and column 'sethasone' where in table 'cards' column 'used' ='0'.

In the second line it goes wrong, without the second line it works fine but i doesn't works as it has to.

Comment: @Dexter sorry, this is still unclear to me. Can you provide some sample data and how you want it to look after it's modified?

Comment: @Mureinik Alright. Ill show only the column's that we need.  
      
[database] - [table] - [column] - [value]

mycard - users - username - ExampleName

mycard - users - cardnumber - 

mycard - users - hasone - 0

That's how it is before the query has did his job.

Now what i want to do is from these table-columns:

mycar - cards - number - 5555555

mycar - cards - used - 1 
mycar - cards - sethasone - 1

mycar - cards - number - 7777777
mycar - cards - used - 0 
mycar - cards - sethasone - 1

mycar - cards - number - 8889333
mycar - cards - used - 0 
mycar - cards - sethasone - 1
...

Comment: ...
it would check which row has used = '0'  and choose only one, i think he auto-gets the first row that has column 'used' with value 0 [LIMIT 1]
on the end it would be edited/inserted. I was thinking to use UPDATE, but im fine with both. I can work around it.

mycard - users - username - ExampleName
mycard - users - cardnumber - 7777777
mycard - users - hasone - 1

Comment: I'm sorry that ^ messed up a bit.
I've uploaded it to pastebin : [link](http://pastebin.com/MN4LqG0e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to write a nested query but you didn't know how to write it. If you want to write select query within insert or update query so before doing this [Click here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) to read about sub-query or nested query.

Comment: Thanks, i will have a deeper look into sub-query's. Im busy with this for hours atm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you're trying to re-create a JOIN between 2 table. What you need to do is to add a "card_id" field into the users table. Then to get the user AND the card you can do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN cards c ON c.id = u.card_id
```